# Perl script within batch script prompts for user input. How do I automatically parse that input within the batch script?

Tags: bash, perl, unix

I have a number of folders and I need to run a Perl script within each one. I create a loop in a batch file and execute Perl within each folder. The problem is that the Perl script prompts for user input and stops the loop. How do i automatically parse the input to the Perl script without the loop breaking to ask for user input?

Sorry if this has been answered before, I am new both to stackoverflow and batch scripting.

```
for (( i = 0; i <= 6; i++ ))      
do

    for (( j = 0 ; j <= 6; j++ )) 
    do
          cd $i$j*
          ~/scripts/script.pl log.out
          #This perl script requires user input, how do I input it here automatically.
          cd ..

done
done
```

Comment: Is it the same input each time the Perl script is run?

Comment: You have identified that the problem is in the Perl code, but haven't shown the Perl code. We need to see it so that we can give the appropriate answer how to automatically supply input.

Comment: Yes the input is the same each time, a number lets say

Comment: a minor point, but ‘cd ..’ can get you in trouble. be explicit ‘cd /dir/where/you/run/the/script’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input is small, you can inline into your script, and feed it to the perl program using the << construct. Otherwise, consider placing the input into a file, and redirecting standard input using <.

```
for (( i = 0; i <= 6; i++ ))      
do

    for (( j = 0 ; j <= 6; j++ )) 
    do
          cd $i$j*
          ~/scripts/script.pl log.out <<__INPUT__
Your Input here
multiple lines are OK
__INPUT__
          #This perl script requires user input, how do I input it here automatically.
          cd ..

    done
done
```

Comment: Or `printf 'Your Input here\nmultiple lines are OK\n' | script.pl`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of here-docs to generate input:

```
$ read -p 'Does this really work? (Y/N) ' OK <<-EOF
Y
EOF
$ echo $OK
Y
```